# opencv translation vector in known unit

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, computational-geometry, homography, homogenous-transformation

Is there any way to compute translation vector in a known unit like 'mm' or 'cm' between two planar objects using corresponding feature points. If yes, please let me know how can I do that.

So far I've tried with Essential Matrix computation (for non planer objects) and didn't get them in a known unit.

Thanking You in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you know the physical distance between some of those points (at least two) on the plane, so to fix the scale. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Without a reference distance, there is no way to tell whether you are looking at two buildings hundred of yards away, or two matchboxes nearby: this is how miniature visual effects in movies are done.

Comment: Thank You @Fransesco Callari for the answer. But I'm still wondering, how the real time visual odometry and mixed reality is achieved. Any idea?

Comment: You do not need absolute scale to render computer graphics objects on top of captured footage, only positioning matters. See the last paragraph in this other answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977800/how-to-find-camera-matrix-for-augmented-reality/10981086#10981086

Comment: Thank You very much @Francesco Callari, that's what I'm exactly looking at.

Answer (score 0):

This [Measuring size of objects in an image with OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) here can help you as a reference I feel.
Hope it helps others as well.